# Why same site acting differently when visiting from different domains?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have registered alternate domain for my original website mnt.mk so it will lead to my website. That second domain is mnt.com.mk 
So far so good.
Now I noticed that site shows differently when accessing from the different domains. Also, I just updated Joomla logged using mnt.mk url, but when I log in using mnt.com.mk it says that joomla has update.

Both domains point to same folder on the hosting and there is only one joomla installation on it.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought that if any domains point to the same hosting it will get the same website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was restrictions from the hosting provider because the mail server was in house... so I fixed the thing with plugin called Domain redirect. Its only job is to open the site on the desired domain.

The only thing to remember is that editing the stuff must be done only on the first domain.

Comment: You may award the green tick to your answer if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, this isn't a Joomla question.
Quickly, some information to help you out:

Although **mnt.com.mk** redirects to **mnt.mk**

This isn't the case for when you are reaching the administrator sites.

**mnt.mk/administrator/**

is not the same as

**mnt.com.mk/administrator/**

Note that:
**mnt.mk** points to **23.227.129.242**

while
**mnt.com.mk** points to **92.55.94.20**

So certainly you haven't setup things as you expect.

<sub>Ask your hosting provider(s) domain registrars for support, or hire someone and give him all the details and access of your hosting accounts and where your domains are, to make the proper configuration for you.</sub>